# Next Run code until Button is clicked again

Tags: javascript, next.js

learning next and stuff and had a question I did not have any success on finding online.

So I have a button

`<button onClick={toggle} className="common-btn">{buttonText}</button>`

I am wanting this button to control how long a section of code is ran. So within the toggle method I update the state and that works just fine. I also run a while loop hoping that if the state ever changed it would break out of the while loop running the code like so

```
...
setRunning(!running)
if(running){
    while(running) 
    {
      console.log("Running")
    }
}

...
```

The issue comes in since it never breaks out of the while loop so even if the state is false it will continue to run the original while loop. Does anyone have any better insight on how to go about this?

Comment: I dont know the *next* framework but if `running` is a separate "local" var you create, then it never changes state simply by calling `setRunning(!running)` because that just passes a parameter of the inverse.

Comment: @mardubbles running is a state, which is setup like `const [running, setRunning] = useState(true);` and running setRunning(!running) will update the state to be the opposite of what it is currently

Comment: Ok I see. Well if thats the logic then, does the "react" engine, break out of while loops in real-time?

Answer (score 0):

```
<button onClick={() =>toggle() } className="common-btn">{buttonText}</button>
setRunning(!running)
if(running){
     While(running) {
      console.log("Running")
      } 
}else{
 console.log("Not Running) 
}
```

Wyh dont you type like this?

Comment: But how does `!running` as an *expression* actually change the state of a variable called `running`? That is how and *when* does `running` as a variable get updated?

Comment: Okey. I will write all code for you then you will understand

Comment: First of all you have to import useState to your component. After that create running and setRunning vareable. And you only can change running width setRunning. Initsial value is true for running and when you click button this will change to false. And when true your console will log running.